# Python logging module doesn't write in log file

Tags: python, logging

I have an issue with my script, I'm trying to create a log file for every call of this function:

```
@begin.subcommand
def sample_mode(sample, folder = None, reference = None, dbsnp = None):
    """ creates a config file for 1 sample

    - setup logging system: {folder}/logs/{sample}_init.log
    - takes in a sample name
    - creates a file: {folder}/{sample}_config.yaml
    """
    # get the current folder if none is given
    if folder == None:
        folder = os.getcwd() 

    # create logs folder if necessary
    if not os.path.isdir("{}/logs".format(folder)):
        os.mkdir("{}/logs".format(folder))

    log_file = setup_log(sample, folder)

    for i in range(1,3):
        try:
            os.path.getsize("{}/{}.{}.fq.gz".format(folder, sample, i))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            log_file.error("{}/{}.{}.fq.gz doesn't exist".format(folder, sample, i))
            return -1

        if os.path.getsize("{}/{}.{}.fq.gz".format(folder, sample, i)) == 0:
            log_file.error("\"{}/{}.{}.fq.gz\" is empty\n".format(folder, sample, i))
            return -1

    # set up logging system
    # logging.basicConfig(filename = "{}/logs/{}_init.log".format(folder, sample), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    # create the config file
    with open("{}/{}_config.yaml".format(folder, sample), "w") as config:
        config.write("sample: \"{}\"\n\n".format(sample))
        log_file.info("Sample name: {}".format(sample))
```

For reference, the setup_log function:

```
def setup_log(sample, folder):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    filename = "{}/logs/{}_init.log".format(folder, sample)

    log_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

    logger.addHandler(log_handler)

    return logger
```

The log file is created but it's empty. However, if i put a wrong sample name, the log file is created and the error message is written.

What an i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code, this should work:

```
import logging

def setup_log(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)   # > set up a new name for a new logger

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # here is the missing line

    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    filename = f"./test_{name}.log"
    log_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

    logger.addHandler(log_handler)

    return logger

def test_log(name):
    logger = setup_log(name)
    logger.info("Just logged from %s", name)   # > old formatting syntax is advised by the logging cookbook

test_log("log1")
test_log("log2")
test_log("log3")
```

The log files were not written because you have to set the logger's level, before to set the level of the handler.

Also, you have to know that `logging.getLogger(name)` returns a singleton. If you call the `getLogger` mfunction with the same name you used before, this will return the existing logger, which could leads you to a very weird situation here... To illustrate it:

```
def test_log(name):
    logger = setup_log(name)
```

is equivalent to

```
def test_log(name):
    setup_log(name)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
```

> More here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: Thank you, it works now. The examples i found online used the setLevel method on the handler object, i guess that's wrong?

Comment: That's not wrong, you can set the level at the root (`logging`) level, at the logger's level and at the handler's level. If the logger's level is ERROR, the handler will never receive the message, no matter what is its level